union and intersection type multiple line formatting with eslint
I'm using eslint.
// package.json
"eslint": "^9.0.0"

In cases like before, I would like to display an error line or change it to after.
// before
type MyTypes = 'whoami' | 'hello' | 'world'

// after
type MyTypes =
  | 'whoami'
  | 'hello'
  | 'world'

Are these rules in eslint or another eslint plugin module?
https://typescriptbook.jp/reference/values-types-variables/union#%E3%83%A6%E3%83%8B%E3%82%AA%E3%83%B3%E5%9E%8B%E3%81%AE%E5%9E%8B%E6%B3%A8%E9%87%88
I found this writing method on the page above (Japanese page).
https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/
I looked for the eslint plugin module, but it doesn't seem to exist.
